# How to enable USB ethernet in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, usb, hardware, ethernet

I have a TD-LTE wireless terminal which can be used as a external 4G network adapter.  It is connected to computer through USB. When I'm using Debian 11, it can provide USB ethernet well. However, when I tried to use it in Arch. I can't access find the USB ethernet.
`ip` doesn't show the external device

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:76:1c:08:1f:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:51:b7:f5:a5:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Maybe Arch requires a special firmware or driver for the device. How can I find it?
`lspci` doesn't show the external device

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
```

In Arch, the device can provide 4G network well. I can connect to the WLAN it provides.
More details:

- OS:Linux 5.17.8-arch1-1
- computer:ThinkPad S3-S440
- TD-TLE terminal vendor: Huawei
  I've turned off USB3.0 mode.

Comment: `lsusb.py -ui`, also `dmesg`.

Comment: `pacman -S usbutils`  has  `lsusb` command to list all devices connected to USB. That might be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following  Stephen Boston's comment, I solved this problem:
First, install 2 software:
`pacman --sync usbutils usb_modeswitch`
Then, get details about the external USB ethernet device (I found that it had been in Mass Storage mode):
`$ lsusb --verbose`
and find:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131  
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing  
Device Descriptor:  
  idVendor           0x12d1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.  
  idProduct          0x14db E353/E3131
```

Change the mode of the device:
`# usb_modeswitch --default-vendor 0x12d1 --default-product 0x14db --huawei-new-mode`
It may work properly now.
Notes: I haven't study `lsusb` or `usb_modeswitch` in details yet. I just found this method worked on my computer.